# Java: Could I have the control of the BufferedWriter?

Tags: java, class, buffer

Could I take the control of the buffer (BufferedWriter) to send the data before it is full?

edit: The scenario is that. We put  String like "Luck" together with other Strings into the buffer (BufferedWriter), then onto a FileWriter. Well, the BufferWriter holds all the data until is full.

Comment: Dude, there are literally thousands of different buffers out there.  How am I supposed to know which one you're talking about?

Comment: @Joe C: BufferedWriter

Comment: You mean like `flush()`?

Comment: I don't know, mine was a question.
I don't know why I have feedback negative, I thought the question was logically correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#flush--) method, which does exactly that.